# How can I filter utc date with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I can't compare dates using the following code. The date in the database is in the utc/iso format for example: 2011-04-11T10:20:30Z. I tried using startAt and it's not filtering my data.

```
db.collection('reservation').startAt(new Date('2011-04-11T10:20:30Z'))
```

this is my data
[image]

Comment: You tagged your question with `firebase-realtime-database`, but the syntax you use is for `google-cloud-firestore`. While the two databases are both path of Firebase, they are completely separate and have their own APIs and tags. Please don't mix the two, and tag with the correct tag.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the data you're trying to filter, as it is stored in the database?

Comment: thank you for your reply. I edited my question.

Comment: Please replace that screenshot with a screenshot from the Firebase console with the data.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm front-end developer and I don't have access to the remote data base. the date in the iso format.